# Questions about determining local extremum by derivative

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

1. [Second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test) in
   Wikipedia says that:

   For a real function of one variable:

   > If the function f is twice
   > differentiable at a stationary point
   > x, meaning that $\ f^{\prime}(x) = 0$
   > , then:
   >
   > If $ f^{\prime\prime}(x) < 0$ then $f$
   > has a local maximum at $x$. If $f^{\prime\prime}(x) > 0$ then $f$
   > has
   > a local minimum at $x$. If $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = 0$, the
   > second
   > derivative test says nothing about the
   > point $x$, a possible inflection
   > point.

   For a function of more than one
   variable:

   > Assuming that all second order partial
   > derivatives of $f$ are continuous on a
   > neighbourhood of a stationary point $x$,
   > then:
   >
   > if the eigenvalues of the Hessian at $x$
   > are all positive, then $x$ is a local
   > minimum. If the eigenvalues are all
   > negative, then $x$ is a local maximum,
   > and if some are positive and some
   > negative, then the point is a saddle
   > point. If the Hessian matrix is
   > singular, then the second derivative
   > test is inconclusive.

   My question is why in the
   multivariate case, the test requires
   the second order partial derivatives
   of $f$ to be continuous on a
   neighbourhood of $x$, while in the
   single variable case, it does not
   need the second derivative to be
   continuous around $x$? Do both also
   require that the first derivative
   and the function itself to be
   continuous around $x$?
2. Similarly, does [first derivative
   test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_derivative_test#Precise_statement_of_first_derivative_test) for $f$ at $x$ need $f$ to
   be continuous and differentiable in
   a neighbourhood of $x$?
3. For [higher order derivative
   test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_derivative_test), it doesn't mention if $f$
   is required to be continuous and
   differentiable in a neighbourhood of
   some point $c$ up to some order. So
   does it only need that $f$ is
   differentiable at $c$ up to order $n$?

Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question (3), the idea is to take the Taylor expansion in order to see which type the critical point is. If the Taylor approximation is
$$ f(x + \epsilon) \approx f(x) + C \epsilon^n, \quad 0 \neq C = \frac{f^{(n)}}{n!} $$ then if $n$ is odd, it's not an optimum at all, whereas if it is even, it's a minimum if $C > 0$ and a maximum if $C < 0$ (it's enough to notice that $x^2$ has a minimum at $0$). In order for the Taylor approximation to work, you need the $n+1$ derivative of $f$ to be continuous, to ensure that the remainder term is continuous in some neighborhood of $x$.

In practice, functions are usually infinitely differentiable, so you shouldn't worry so much about the existence of derivatives.

For question (1), we do the same Taylor business and get an expansion
$$f(\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}) \approx f(\vec{x}) + \vec{\epsilon}' \nabla f(\vec{x}) + \frac{1}{2} \vec{\epsilon}' Hf(\vec{x}) \vec{\epsilon}, $$
where $\nabla f$ is the gradient and $Hf$ is the Hessian, the matrix of second derivatives. If $Hf(\vec{x})$ is positive definite with smallest eigenvalue $\lambda > 0$, then $$\vec{\epsilon}' Hf(\vec{x}) \vec{\epsilon} \geq \lambda \|\vec{\epsilon}\|^2, $$ and we get a minimum (since the error is $O(\|\vec{\epsilon}\|^3)$).

Some funky math allows you somehow to deduce all of this even without having the extra derivative required for having a bounded Taylor's remainder term, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 3):

For your second question: Yes: you need the derivative of $f$ to be defined in a puncture neighborhood of $x$ for the first derivative test to even make sense: you need to know the sign of $f'$ on $(x-\delta,x)$ and on $(x,x+\delta)$ for some $\delta\gt 0$ to be able to apply the test; this automatically requires continuity as well on those intervals. And of course, if $f$ is not continuous at $x$, then you cannot derive a conclusion about the value of $f$ at $x$. Take
$$f(x) =\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-x & \mbox{if $x\lt 0$,}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \mbox{if $x=0$,}\\
x+\frac{3}{4} & \mbox{if $x\gt 0$.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then the derivative is negative on $(-\infty,0)$, and positive on $(0,\infty)$; it is undefined on $x=0$. But $f$ has neither a local maximum nor a local minimum at $0$.

In fact, the First Derivative Test is usually stated for functions that are continuous.

Comment: Thanks as always! I guess it is harder to understand for Second and Higher Order Derivative Tests than for the First Derivative Test.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the continuity of the partials is not *needed*, twice total differentiability *at the point* is sufficient, so the one and the higher dimensional cases are totally analogous. *But* the existence of the second order partials is *insufficient* for twice total differentiability, so the Hessian is not necessarily the second total derivative just because the second partials exist, and you can compute the Hessian. But their continuity is a simple, sufficient condition for twice differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat handwaving answer to question (1):
To check whether $f(a,b)$ is a local minimum, you want to compare the value $f(a+h,b+k)$ to the value $f(a,b)$.
The $x$-derivatives at $(a,b)$ tell you something about how $f(a+h,b)$ compares to $f(a,b)$,
but, unless you assume continuity, the $y$-derivatives at $(a,b)$ don't tell you anything about how $f(a+h,b+k)$ compares to $f(a+h,b)$ (since that comparison involves the $y$-derivatives at the point $(a+h,b)$ rather than at $(a,b)$).